# Using Automapper to map view model to model causes Entity Framework to delete grandchildren rows

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, automapper

I have an MVVM application using Entity Framework Core and using Automapper to map between view models and models.  I have some parent/child relationships set up in Entity Framework.  I'm having a problem where Automapper seems to cause my grandchild table to have its data deleted.

My model classes looks like this

```
public class Parent
{
   public string Key1 { get; set; }

   public int Value1 { get; set; }
   public int Value2 { get; set; }

   public virtual List<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
   public string Key1 { get; set; }
   public string Key2 { get; set; }

   public int Value1 { get; set; }
   public int Value2 { get; set; }

   public virtual List<Grandchild> Grandchildren { get; set; }
}

public class Grandchild
{
   public string Key1 { get; set; }
   public string Key2 { get; set; }
   public string Key3 { get; set; }

   public int Value1 { get; set; }
   public int Value2 { get; set; }
}
```

I'm using Fluent API to set up my mappings like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
   base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);           

   modelBuilder.Entity<Parent>(eb =>
   {
      eb.HasKey(k => new { k.Key1 })
   });
   modelBuilder.Entity<Parent>.HasMany(p => p.Children);

   modelBuilder.Entity<Child>(eb =>
   {
      eb.HasKey(k => new { k.Key1, k.Key2 })
   });
   modelBuilder.Entity<Child>.HasMany(p => p.Grandchildren);

   modelBuilder.Entity<Grandchild>(eb =>
   {
      eb.HasKey(k => new { k.Key1, k.Key2, k.Key3 })
   });
}
```

When I get my model from the database, I do it like this:

```
public Parent GetParentModel(string key)
{
   return myContext.Parents
      .Include(p => p.Children)
         .ThenInclude(p => p.Grandchildren)
      .FirstOrDefault(p => p.Key1 == key);
}
```

After I get my `Parent` model from the database and prior to calling `SaveChanges()` on my EF context, I use Automapper to map the view model to the model like this (the view model has the same `Key1`, `Value1`, etc. fields as the model).

```
// myModel is of type Parent
mapper.Map(myViewModel, myModel, myViewModel.GetType(), myModel.GetType());
```

After the above line of code, I've used to debugger to see what's being changed in my objects.  No objects get deleted in `myModel.Children` or `myModel.Children.Grandchildren`, and the objects look correct in the Watch window.

Even though the C# objects are correct, the rows in the `Grandchildren` table get deleted.  The rows get deleted whether I add, modify, delete, or do nothing to `myModel.Children` and/or `myModel.Children.Grandchildren`

I'm pretty sure the problem is related to Automapper, because if I add/edit `myModel.Children.Grandchildren` via code, the rows do not get deleted and the updates do get written to the database correctly.

Comment: Research AutoMapper.Collection.

Comment: In `ChildViewModel`, the 'Grandchildren` property is of type `List<Grandchild>` (rather than `List<GrandchildViewModel`>), so I don't understand why I would need a mapping for that.  But I tried adding a mapping from `Grandchild` to `Grandchild`, and now the problem is that when I add a new `Grandchild` to my view model and then map and save my context, I get a duplicate key error and the `Grandchild` element that already existed in the database gets added to my C# `Grandchildren` list for a second time.

Comment: I don't know if it makes a difference, but in my view model, all my collections are `ObservableCollection`s.

Comment: The sooner you understand the point of that package, the sooner you'll solve your problem.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize it was a separate package.  I thought you were saying I should read the Automapper documentation about collections.  I'll look at that package now.  Thanks for your help.